# With Rails, how to send the browser a json object versus a json string?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm using the following in rails to push to node.js:

```
NodePush[].trigger('unit', 'join', {:id =>record.user_id, :name => record.user.name}, record.unit_id)
```

Problem I'm having is console is logging the results as:

```
{"id":7154,"name":"Medallions"}
```

What I want is for the console to output an object like so:

```
Object
 id: 7154
 name: "Medallions"
```

Any suggestions on how to update the rails code to create an object? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you push data from Rails to Node, you're pushing JSON. If you want to see the JavaScript object that Node reconstitutes on its end, you need to log the object after it's parsed, or alternately, explicitly call `JSON.parse(str)` when you log the object to the console (where `str` is the JSON string).